# Difference between sentences of cronjobs

Tags: php, cron

What is the difference between these two cron commands:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/username/public_html/...

/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/...
```

the first one is "**-f**" and the second one "**-q**"
Cronjob works fine with both of them. I just don't know what is the difference between them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

**f:**

> -f    --file
>   Parse and execute the specified file. The -f is optional and may be omitted - providing just the filename to execute is sufficient.

**q:**

> -q    --no-header
>   Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).

Since `-f` is optional and `-q` only applies to the CGI-version of PHP (you are running the regular command line interpreter, however), this leaves you with the same command twice:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/...
```

To explicitly answer your question: In this case, there is **no difference** between those two commands!

Comment: Added some explanation to my answer. If this answers your question, please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The two options are of PHP command.

```
 --no-header
   -q             Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).
```

and

```
--file file
   -f file        Parse and execute file
```

are shown in the help doc of PHP, you can check them with `man php` in your terminal.

Also the synopsis contains

```
php [options] [ -f ] file [[--] args...]
```

where the `-f` seems not to be necessary.